# How to check if an integer is in a given range?

Tags: java, comparison

Hoping for something more elegant than

```
if (i>0 && i<100)
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: The obvious solution is to have a `class RangeChecker<Integer>` and I'm sure you can fill in the details from there.

Comment: I was just hoping for something more elegant, like i.inRange(0..100). but i guess what sarnold said is true.

Comment: bear in mind i come from ruby and python.

Comment: maybe OP was hoping for a semantic possibility akin to BETWEEN in `SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE aDate BETWEEN lower AND upper`

Comment: Just as point of interest, Python allows the syntax `0 < i < 100` for tests like this.

Comment: apache commons class [org.apache.commons.lang.math.IntRange](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html)
might suits you.

Comment: @GregHewgill In Common Lisp, you'd do `(< 0 i 100)`.

Comment: I guess the main problem in this case is that JaCoCo says you don't cover all 4 cases, since 4th case is impossible ( `i < 0` and `i > 100` ).

Comment: Kotlin allow  - `(i in 0..10)`

Answer (score 257):

You could add spacing ;)

```
if (i > 0 && i < 100)
```

Comment: don't cramp my style! no i usually space it like that.

Comment: On suggestion is that since we'd typically write something like "0 < i < 100", it's nice to follow that as much as possible to make the code a bit easier to read: `0 < i && i < 100`.  It's a little bit weird to have the constant on the left in `0 < i`, but I think it's worth it to have the overall expression that looks most like `0 < ... < 100`.

Comment: `N > 2 && N < 5` the value N is between 2 and 5

Answer (score 63):

For those using commons lang an option is to use [Range](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html):

```
Range<Integer> myRange = Range.between(100, 500);
if (myRange.contains(200)){
    // do something
}
```

Also see: [how to construct a apache commons 3.1 Range<Integer> object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626491/how-to-construct-a-apache-commons-3-1-rangeinteger-object)

Comment: This is very inefficient though

Answer (score 38):

I think

```
if (0 < i && i < 100)
```

is more elegant. Looks like maths equation.

If you are looking for something special you can try:

```
Math.max(0, i) == Math.min(i, 100)
```

at least it uses library.

Comment: Note that the 2nd solution is inclusive, 1st is not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Math.min(i, 99)`? Because if I enter `100` it will still return true. I think `Math.max(0, i) == Math.min(i, 100)` works for  `0 < i <= 100`

Comment: @Irshu Not quite -  because if `i = 0` then `Math.max(0, i) == Math.min(i, 99)` still evaluates to `0 == 0`

Answer (score 20):

```java
ValueRange range = java.time.temporal.ValueRange.of(minValue, maxValue);
range.isValidIntValue(x);
```

- it returns `true` if  `minValue <= x <= MaxValue` - i.e. within the range
- it returns `false` if  `x < minValue` **or** `x > maxValue`  - i.e.
  out of range

Use with `if` condition as shown below:

```java
int value = 10;
if (ValueRange.of(0, 100).isValidIntValue(value)) {
    System.out.println("Value is with in the Range.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Value is out of the Range.");
}
```

The below program checks, if any of the passed integer value in the `hasTeen` method is within the range of 13 (*inclusive*) to 19 (*inclusive*).

---

```java
import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;
  
public class TeenNumberChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hasTeen(9, 99, 19));
        System.out.println(hasTeen(23, 15, 42));
        System.out.println(hasTeen(22, 23, 34));
    }

    public static boolean hasTeen(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int thirdNumber) {

        ValueRange range = ValueRange.of(13, 19);
        System.out.println("*********Int validation Start ***********");
        System.out.println(range.isIntValue());
        System.out.println(range.isValidIntValue(firstNumber));
        System.out.println(range.isValidIntValue(secondNumber));
        System.out.println(range.isValidIntValue(thirdNumber));
        System.out.println(range.isValidValue(thirdNumber));
        System.out.println("**********Int validation End**************");

        if (range.isValidIntValue(firstNumber) || range.isValidIntValue(secondNumber) || range.isValidIntValue(thirdNumber)) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

> `true` as 19 is part of range
>
> `true` as 15 is part of range
>
> `false` as all three value passed out of range

Comment: Nice, I have used it in if condition like - `if(ValueRange.of(90, 100).isValidIntValue(91)) { "Value is in range." }`

Comment: **NOTE:** actually the class `ValueRange` is not *directly* meant for pure integer comparison, but rather for (quote from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ValueRange.html), emphasis mine): "The range of valid values for a **date-time** field."

Answer (score 13):

I think its already elegant way for comparing range. But, this approach cause you to write extra unit tests to satisfy all `&&` cases.

So, you can use any of the below approach to avoid writing extra unit tests.

**Using Java 8 Streams:**

```
if(IntStream.rangeClosed(0,100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(i))
```

**Using Math class:**

```
if(Math.max(0, i) == Math.min(i, 100))
```

Personally I recommend the second approach because it won't end up creating an Array of the size equal to the range you want to check.

Comment: You have to write all the unit tests nontheless. The difference is that it's probably not noted by code checking tools.

Comment: @kap Obviously one should write all valid unit tests. But, the approach used in OP will require a test case which is practically impossible to cover i.e. false && false. That’s why I mentioned a way to avoid covering this invalid extra test case.

Comment: The Streams solution is awesomely bad. Consider a bigger range of -2.000.000.000 and 2.000.000.000. Creating a list of four billion entries, just to check if one value is in it, is simply madness.

Comment: @SvenDöring Obviously its not a good option for bigger range and I had already mentioned it in my last line of the answer. Also, please note that this answer is for the range mentioned in the question i.e. 0 - 100

Answer (score 8):

I don't see how that's not elegant, but if you repeat the expression often, then it's a good idea to put it into a method, e.g.

```
class MathUtil
{
   public static boolean betweenExclusive(int x, int min, int max)
   {
       return x>min && x<max;    
   }
}
```

This is particularly true if you mix exclusive and inclusive comparisons. The method name can help avoid typos, such as using < when <= should have been used. The method can also take care of ensuring that min < max etc..

Comment: It is a good idea, until someone puts in `boolean accepted = MathUtil.betweenExclusive(min,max,x);` and mungles the order. :(

Comment: I know! Ouch. In those cases, a Range object can be useful.

Comment: My RangeChecker object was actually a joke, but in hindsight, it actually isn't that bad of a solution (even if it is overkill.)

Comment: It would be better if it were a method directly defined in `Integer` class. There is zero confusion when you do; `myNum.isBetween(min, max)`

Comment: Simple example: I have list of people with their ages, and want to check, if each of them is old aged, middle aged, child or toddler. I can have named ranges of ages, and then my code is quite readable. Or I can have lots of > and < and my code is gibberish.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for something more original than

```
if (i > 0 && i < 100)
```

you can try this

```
import static java.lang.Integer.compare;
...
if(compare(i, 0) > compare(i, 100))
```

Answer (score 4):

[This guy](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mkarg/archive/2011/01/01/generic-range-class) made a nice [Range](https://headcrashing.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/range-class/) class.

Its use however will not yield nice code as it's a generic class. You'd have to type something like:

```
if (new Range<Integer>(0, 100).contains(i))
```

or (somewhat better if you implement first):

```
class IntRange extends Range<Integer>
....
if (new IntRange(0,100).contains(i))
```

Semantically both are IMHO nicer than what Java offers by default, but the memory overhead, performance degradation and more typing overall are hadly worth it. Personally, I like [mdma's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5574083/1760858) better.

Comment: Page Not Found for Range class URL.

Answer (score 4):

Google's Java Library Guava also implements [Range](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Range;

Range<Integer> open = Range.open(1, 5);
System.out.println(open.contains(1)); // false
System.out.println(open.contains(3)); // true
System.out.println(open.contains(5)); // false

Range<Integer> closed = Range.closed(1, 5);
System.out.println(closed.contains(1)); // true
System.out.println(closed.contains(3)); // true
System.out.println(closed.contains(5)); // true

Range<Integer> openClosed = Range.openClosed(1, 5);
System.out.println(openClosed.contains(1)); // false
System.out.println(openClosed.contains(3)); // true
System.out.println(openClosed.contains(5)); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( 0 < i && i < 100)  

if ( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' )
```

Comment: Apart from the inconsistent spacing in the first example perfect!

Comment: Too bad the 6 character rule prevents any fixes to the spacing.

Comment: A better char check is `if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z'))`

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ Even better: `Character.isLetter(c)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
if (lowerBound <= val && val < upperBound)
or
if (lowerBound <= val && val <= upperBound)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Spring data you can also use the Range object from Spring.

```
range = new org.springframework.data.domain.Range(3, 8);
range.contains(5) // will return true.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cts

```
    // Exclusive    
    public boolean isOrdered(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
        return n1 < n2 && n2 < n3 ;
    }
```

call it like to see it is one of 1 to 99

```
    if (isOrdered(0,i,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you check is an integer is in a range.  Greater than the lower bound, less than the upper bound.  Trying to be clever with subtraction will likely not do what you want.

Comment: Trying to be clever with subtraction can lead to integer over- or underflow and give you an incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (i>0 && i<100) {}
```

it will work at least ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test whether the value of `i` is in the range [0..100), and you want the boolean result, then

```
i >= 0 && i < 100
```

is fine and will give you `true` or `false`. If you are willing to throw an exception if the value is out of range, you can use the built-in [checkIndex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#checkIndex%28int,int%29) method

```
Objects.checkIndex(i, 100)
```

which will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if out of range. Granted, it is not a general solution, and is really only prettier if your context is one in which your range check is being done for checking array bounds, but it has the advantage of not needed any third party libraries, which is nice for small programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if strategy. Seems solid.

```
int num = 5;
    
    //random values; can be changed
    int a = 3;
    int b = 7;
    
    if (num >= 3 && num <= 7) {
        //Your Code Here
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32190536)

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this program to **check the value of 3 integer parameters against a range**.

I have created a separate method to check the range of the each value using if/else-if statements.

I hope this helps someone.

```
public class TeenNumberChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        boolean isTeen = hasTeen();

    }

    public static boolean hasTeen(int valueOne, int valueTwo, int valueThree) {
        
        
        if (valueOne > 13 && valueOne < 19) {
            
            return true;
            
        } else if (valueTwo > 13 && valueTwo < 19) {
            
            return true;
            
        } else if (valueThree > 13 && valueThree < 19) {
            
            return true;
            
        }else {
            
            return false;
            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if(i <= 0 || i >=100)

It will work.

Comment: that's negating the original condition and not providing a more elegant solution

Answer (score -1):

If you are confident that numbers are stored in 2's complement form:

```
return  ((x-low) <= (high-low));
```

A more general and safer solution would be:

```
return ((x-high)*(x-low) <= 0);
```

Comment: In what way is it elegant?

Answer (score -1):

```
 Range<Long> timeRange = Range.create(model.getFrom(), model.getTo());
    if(timeRange.contains(systemtime)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "green!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```