# How to construct an Apache Commons Lang Range<Integer> object?

Tags: java, integer, range, apache-commons

How can I create a Apache Commons Lang 3.1 `Range<Inreger>` object?

[The JavaDocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) say:

> "*An immutable range of objects from a minimum to maximum point inclusive.*"

> "*The objects need to either be implementations of Comparable or you need to supply a Comparator.*"

But when I try:

```
Range<Integer> range = new Range<Integer>(100, 200);
```

I get an error in my IDE that says required arguments are Integer, Integer, comparator.

Even though `Integer` implements the `Comparable` interface and thus I shouldn't need a extra comparator.

Can someone give me an example of how to construct the above described `Range<Integer>` object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor of Range appears to be private so a static method may be the preferred way of constructing the object.

For example, it looks like you could use the static method `between` to construct a Range:

```
Range.between(100, 200);
```

However there are other static methods, it just depends what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`Range` is an abstract class. Use `IntRange range = new IntRange(100, 200)` instead.

Comment: IntRange is the Range object in the old apache commons versions (before 3). I need to get intersects of ranges and this is not yet available in the old IntRange object.

Comment: @WillamS: Oh, then I have an old version lying around.