# Regular Expression Union and subtracion for numeric

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to have a union of regular expression and subtraction,I am able work range only like. `String regex = "[1-3[5-7]]";` but need different type of numbers with range and at the same time union also like `String regex = "\b([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-5]&&[191])\b";` In this line am able to match 1 to 55 and also match 191.it is not working.Can any one give the suggestion where the problem getting. I tried for numeric range like below.

```
public class NumericRangeRegex {



    public String baseRange(String num, boolean up, boolean leading1) {

        char c = num.charAt(0);
        char low  = up ? c : leading1 ? '1' : '0';
        char high = up ? '9' : c;

        if (num.length() == 1)
            return charClass(low, high);

        String re = c + "(" + baseRange(num.substring(1), up, false) + ")";

        if (up) low++; else high--;

        if (low <= high)
            re += "|" + charClass(low, high) + nDigits(num.length() - 1);

        return re;
    }

    private String charClass(char b, char e) {
        return String.format(b==e ? "%c" : e-b>1 ? "[%c-%c]" : "[%c%c]", b, e);
    }

    private String nDigits(int n) {
        return nDigits(n, n);
    }

    private String nDigits(int n, int m) {
        return "[0-9]" + String.format(n==m ? n==1 ? "":"{%d}":"{%d,%d}", n, m);
    }

    private String eqLengths(String from, String to) {

        char fc = from.charAt(0), tc = to.charAt(0);

        if (from.length() == 1 && to.length() == 1)
            return charClass(fc, tc);

        if (fc == tc)
            return fc + "("+rangeRegex(from.substring(1), to.substring(1))+")";

        String re = fc + "(" + baseRange(from.substring(1), true, false) + ")|"
                + tc + "(" + baseRange(to.substring(1),  false, false) + ")";

        if (++fc <= --tc)
            re += "|" + charClass(fc, tc) + nDigits(from.length() - 1);

        return re;
    }    

    private String nonEqLengths(String from, String to) {
        String re = baseRange(from,true,false) + "|" + baseRange(to,false,true);
        if (to.length() - from.length() > 1)
            re += "|[1-9]" + nDigits(from.length(), to.length() - 2);
        return re;
    }

    public String run(int n, int m) {
        return  "\\b0*?("+ rangeRegex("" + n, "" + m) +")\\b";
    }

    public String rangeRegex(String n, String m) {
        return  n.length() == m.length() ? eqLengths(n, m)  : nonEqLengths(n, m);
    }
}
```

Comment: `[191]` won't match `191` but _one_ character out of 1 or 9. You probably want `...|191) ` instead, i.e. use that as a literal sequence.

Comment: may I know how to work with 191 and not only 191.this value come dynamic and also need subtracion

Comment: If you want to also match `191`, do as first comment says, and also double the backslashes for the ``\b`` word-boundary pattern, i.e. use `"\\b([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-5]|191)\\b"`

Comment: What does *"also need subtracion"* mean? You haven't shown anything about what you mean by "subtraction". --- If you meant something like "match any 3-digit number *except* `666`", then use a zero-width negative look-ahead like this: `"\\b(?!666)\\d{3}\\b"`

Comment: regex is unsuited to calculation. Extract the numbers and check ranges. you can parse numbers with (\d+) if they are whole numbers ...then int.tryparse them and use whatever calculation you need

Comment: No I need regex pattern only. for example In the above regex what ever in question is accept 1 to 55 range and also need to accept 191.If I dont want to 12 and 41 to 47 values.Then what is the regular expression?

Comment: For eg: In alphabetic it'll be like [a-z&&[^bc]]

Comment: @ShivaGoudA do you still need the answer?

Comment: yes I need solution for that.I tried like this also  \b0*?(^(?:(?!25).)$|[0-9]|5([0-7])|[1-4][0-9]|2000)\b

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the wrong track. You should simply extract and parse the numeric values and do the calculation in your regular programming language, as recommended by Patrick.

You can still create a wrapper class that helps to check numeric ranges using a simple function like

```
public static boolean between(int i, int minValueInclusive, int maxValueInclusive) {
    return (i >= minValueInclusive && i <= maxValueInclusive);
}
```

or use [commons.lang.Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626491/how-to-construct-a-apache-commons-3-1-rangeinteger-object):

```
Range<Integer> myRange = Range.between(1, 55);
if (myRange.contains(value)){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on conditions Ill try for union and subtraction is `^(?!250)0*?([0-9]|2(5([0-5])|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|2000)$. In this we are matching 1 to 255 range and 2000 numeric number(union) and for negate 250(subtraction).It's working fine.