# In java, can we use both else and else if in ternary operator and construct 3 conditions in the same statement?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

for example,

```java
int number = 10;

number > 99 && < 1000 ? "three digit number" : "not a three digit number";
```

result is : not a three digit number.

but i want to print a statement "two digit number" if the number is > 9 and less than 100,
in the same statement without requiring a seperate condition to code.

we can do this with if and elseif statements.
but is there a way to do this with ternary operator in java?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574058/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-in-a-given-range for other ideas.

Comment: Nesting ternary if-else statements is quickly becoming unreadable. I would advise you not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a second ternary expression as the "else" condition achieves the result you're looking for:

```java
int number = 10;
String result = number > 99 && number < 1000 ? "three digit number" :
        (number > 9 && number < 100 ? "two digit number" : "not a two or three digit number");
```

Note that this may be considered less readable than the equivalent if/else if block, so this is a technique to use sparingly.

Comment: as i can see u wrote a complete different statement for two digit expression.but is there a wayto adjust this as a three word statement after the "three digit number" in te first line?

Comment: @sravanTG No, there's no ternary-style expression with more than three parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nested Ternary operation if you want to use else-if in ternary operator, but note this is less readable.

```
int num = 5;
String result = (num > 9)?((num>99 && num<1000)?"Three digit number":"Two digit number"):"Single digit number";
System.out.println("Result = "+result);
```